# Can I use @TeamAreas macro in notifications

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automation, notifications, area

We have an organization with multiple teams and each team has multiple areas assigned to them. I want to have a notification set up where when a work item is created for my team (in one of my teams' areas). I dont want to add each area to my notification.

In Queries I can do Area Path = @TeamAreas,but I see no such thing for notifications. Is this a feature coming?

Comment: "*Is this a feature coming?*" In what product, exactly? Why not just ask the vendor themselves?

Comment: I added the Azure-devops tags